# go4.org/reflectutil missing function body

Tags: percona

Code can be found in https://github.com/percona/percona-toolkit/tree/3.0.11/src/go/pt-mongodb-query-digest

/go/src/github.com/percona/percona-toolkit/src/go/pt-mongodb-query-digest: GOARCH=s390x go build

```
# github.com/percona/percona-toolkit/vendor/go4.org/reflectutil
../../../vendor/go4.org/reflectutil/swapper_unsafe.go:106:6: missing function body
../../../vendor/go4.org/reflectutil/swapper_unsafe_15.go:16:6: missing function body
```

Any idea on this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you check the code of that **dependency** you will find:

`103 // memmove copies size bytes from src to dst.
104 // The memory must not contain any pointers.
105 //go:noescape
106 func memmove(dst, src unsafe.Pointer, size uintptr)`

The function is implemented in Assembly, in the `asm_*` files but it is not implemented for your platform (`s390x`). Also, you please be aware that (`s390x`) is not formally supported for Percona Toolkit either.

BTW, I am the Percona Toolkit maintainer.

Comment: Thats great. Is it possible to add support for s390x?

Answer (score 0):

go4.org/reflectutil does not have support for s390x. Making similar changes as in [link](https://github.com/go4org/go4/commit/034d17a462f7b2dcd1a4a73553ec5357ff6e6c6e)  for s390x worked for me.